# Kernel panics when attempting to use non-mirrored dual monitors w/ ATI x1900

Tags: 12.04, ati, multiple-monitors, radeon

I think it may be related to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/994490), but I'm not sure. I took a picture of the kernel panic with my phone, and here's the (I think) interesting part of the panic:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
Pid: 3003, comm: Xorg Tainted: P    D W  O 3.2.0-29-generic #46-Ubuntu
Call Trace:
panic occurred, switching back to text console
```

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this, or add value to an existing bug report?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a work-around for this issue.

1. Downgrade xorg-input-edev from 2.7.0 -> 2.6.99. I utilized the
   instructions on this page[1].
2. Open Ubuntu's display program (System Settings->Displays) and move the left screen to the right; apply changes.
3. Move the right screen back to the left.

I have no idea what bug I'm sneaking around, so I hope this is fixed in xorg-input-edev 7.1.

1 - http://blog.shevin.info/2012/05/how-to-fix-dual-monitor-freeze-in.html